# Use aws cloudtrail to collect application logs

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it possible to use cloud trail to recieve custom logs like application logs, access logs, security logs?

And cloud trail keeps the logs for how long?

Answer (score 3):

You might be thinking of [CloudWatch Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html), which does capture, provide search, and groom custom logs from EC2 instances.  The retention grooming rules are configurable.

Answer (score 2):

No. CloudTrail is for AWS APIs activity only. It logs the activity for the last 7 days of API activity for supported services. The list only includes API activity for create, modify, and delete API calls. You can optionally save the logs in S3 buckets for historic API activity.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure VPC flow logs, CloudTrail logs and AWS Config logs with CloudWatch. You can setup a S3 bucket with lifecycle policies enabled to retain logs forever. Refer [this](https://medium.com/@manojf/fortify-your-aws-castle-57b84fa3305a).